bluetooth speaker not discovered on ubuntu 24.04
On Ubuntu 24.04, tried to connect my JBL (Flip 4) speaker and my JPL headphones via an USB TP-Link bluetooth dongle.
It discovers my Android phone, but not these JBL devices :(
Any suggestion(s)?
TIA,
Adrian.

I can only suggest making certain that they both are not paired (connected) with anything else. and then place them in pairing mode, refresh ubuntu bluetooh screen to see if they show up.
To unpair them from like your phone (or other device), just turn off Bluetooth or click on device and choose forget (but this means you will have to pair again if you want to use device with phone).  you must follow your devices instructions for pairing, normally a combination of buttons to press at power on.
I had to do this when switching my bluetooth speakers from my phone to ubuntu.
